# Two divs will not float beside eachother

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm not sure where I am falling short but I cannot figure out why my two divs will not float beside one another.

I created a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3XUy/

```
<body>
<div class="container">
        <div class="nav">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/about">About Me</a></li>         
                    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="contentImage">
            <img src="RD.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>
                Pinterest Banksy 90's organic salvia....
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thank you!

Comment: We'll need to see the CSS for each div element. You would also want to put .contentImage and .content inside it's own containing div - this way the DIV elements will know where it's restrictions are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The padding-right that you have on one of your divs is making them add up to more than 100% and wrap.  You can do it different ways, like putting a smaller div inside the 50% div causing the trouble.

Comment: Way to go around this is to add margin in '.contentImage img' instead

Comment: Ah, thank you!  I set the width of both the divs to 50% and this seemed to solve the issue.  Thanks again!

Comment: @ryandonohue a solution would also be to add `box-sizing: border-box` (-moz-box-sizing: border-box for FF) to your divs which will mean that if you set the width to 50% the padding would be included in this width. I've found that using box-sizing while working with percent is really the easiest sollution.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you set a width in percentages, the browser will interpret that as a number greater than 100% and wrap. Also, any added padding will trigger it.

Consider:

```
.contentImage {
    width: 49.5%;
    padding: 0;
}

.content { width: 49.5%; }
```